# line break in NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array, how do I make a line break?

```
NSArray *stringsArray2 = @[
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km",betweenDistance/1000],
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km",betweenDistance3/1000],
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km",betweenDistance4/1000]
                              ];
    NSString * combinedStuff = [stringsArray2 componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
    UILabel *label3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200)];
    label3.text = combinedStuff;
    [self.view addSubview:label3];
```

Comment: can  u explain more...??

Comment: maybe you miss `label3.numberOfLines = 0; label3.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;`?

Comment: So.. You're attempting to merge the various parts with a newline as the delimiter between the original parts?

Comment: @Chandan Singh look on my array (stringsArray2), i want to see on display of iphone something like this: Distance is 1.00 km <line break> Distance is 2.00 km <line break>, but if i insert "/n" in componentsJoinedByString:@"/n" i see only Distance is 1.00 km and the second and third line is not reflected but if I leave empty componentsJoinedByString:@"" the entire array will be printed on a single line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your are using wrong escape sequence character.

Try this code

```
NSArray *stringsArray2 = @[
                               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km",100.0],
                               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km",200.0],
                               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km",300.0]
                               ];
    NSString * combinedStuff = [stringsArray2 componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
    NSLog(@"combinedStuff %@",combinedStuff);
    UILabel *label3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 300)];
    label3.text = combinedStuff;
    label3.numberOfLines = 0;
    label3.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    [self.view addSubview:label3];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You can create the string link this:

```
str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km \n Distance is %f km \nDistance is %f km ",betweenDistance/1000,betweenDistance3/1000,betweenDistance4/1000];
```

Now use the `str` string to print on the Label.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this piece of code:

```
NSString * combinedStuff = [stringsArray2 componentsJoinedByString:@"/n"];
```

With this:

```
NSString * combinedStuff = [stringsArray2 componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

Answer (score 0):

**"\n"** is not parsed by NSString as line break, you have to use **"\\n"** for creating the line break.

Comment: @Agent what did you mean? :)

Answer (score 0):

Set numberOfLines to 0 to allow for any number of lines.

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Update the label frame to match the size of the text using `sizeWithFont:`.                                                         If you don't do this your text will be vertically centered or cut off.

```
CGSize labelSize = [label.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font}];
label.frame = CGRectMake(
label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y, 
label.frame.size.width, labelSize.height);
```